# how to keep numpy array when saving pandas dataframe to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with one of the columns as images. Each row of that column is an image as a 2d `numpy.array`. I saved the `DataFrame` to a `csv` file with `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`.  However, when I open the `csv` file, the column becomes string instead of a `numpy.array`.

How can read the `csv` file and keep the `numpy.array`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To read the `numpy.array` from the csv file, you can provide a converter function to `pandas.read_csv`.

**Code:**

```
import ast
import numpy as np
def from_np_array(array_string):
    array_string = ','.join(array_string.replace('[ ', '[').split())
    return np.array(ast.literal_eval(array_string))
```

**Test Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

image = np.array([[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4]])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['image name1', image],
     ['image name2', image],
     ],
    columns=['names', 'images']).set_index('names')
print(df)
df.to_csv('sample.csv')

df2 = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', converters={'images': from_np_array})
print(df2)
```

**Results:**

```
                               images
names                                
image name1  [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4]]
image name2  [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4]]

         names                    images
0  image name1  [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4]]
1  image name2  [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  what is the purpose of  replace('[ ', '[')? @Stephen Rauch

Comment: A general question  is:  generally, should I store the image as flattened 1d array in dataframe? @Stephen Rauch

Comment: The replace removed some spaces, because later I replace spaces with ',' and a comma there would have been a problem.

Comment: I have not studied the csv parser in detail, so could not answer with authority as to the best format, but I can say that the line feeds in the non-flattened arrays are kinda weird.

Comment: And if you need to get hold of the array in `images` field of the dataframe `df2` inside a python variable, use: `my_images = np.array(df2['images'].values.tolist())`.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of sleepless nights! After a lot of work I realized I shouldn't have stored my 2d numpy arrays in dataframe, but couldn't go back on my work. Thanks a lot!