# How to read_csv correctly for dataFrame with Int64 Array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following is a simplied version of the issue.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'key': [1,1,2,2], 'val': [3,4,5,5]})
df['val'] = df['val'].astype('Int64') # read_csv can't read Int64 array properly by default
df = df.groupby('key')['val'].agg(['unique'])
display(df)
df.to_csv('test')
df = pd.read_csv('test', index_col=0)
display(df)
```

And this is what I got

[image]

How can I read the unique column data correctly? Thanks

---

Thanks for @hide1nbush 's pointer. I resolved it using converter.

```py
import ast
def convert_int64_array(array_string):
    return pd.array(ast.literal_eval(array_string.split("\n")[1]), dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
df = pd.read_csv('test', index_col=0, converters={'unique': convert_int64_array})
```

But I wonder if there is a easier way to do this.

[image]

---

I found that using **pickle** format is the easiest way to round trip the dataFrame as file. I don't need to worry about index, int64 etc. See [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d) to understand the difference between some major formats.

Comment: Have you try the method mentioned in this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755214/how-to-keep-numpy-array-when-saving-pandas-dataframe-to-csv ?

Comment: Since your data is structured (a numpy array in cells), I recommend saving with binary (pickle, feather, etc), not text csv file.

Comment: @hide1nbush Thanks for the pointer! Updated my question. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for the suggestion. I'm new to pandas and started with csv. I read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d) and feather seems to be a good option for me.